# Unique Identifier for a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, database

Can anyone think of a unique identifier which exists in every database and persists through restoring that I can white-list with?

We have hundreds of databases restored locally which all started off from the same blank template. This list of restored databases changes constantly and so its not viable to use `database_guid` from `sys.database_recovery_status` to verify the database identity.

I can identify the database by hashing some GUIDs used in the early stages of the databases development, GUID's which will never be removable, however this only deals with part of the problem - what if there are two versions of the same database?

Eg a Live to Test is performed, the GUIDs are the same but I need a way to uniquely identify which is Live and which is Test without being reliant on the people restoring them conforming to the correct naming conventions.

Comment: Your definition of "database identity" doesn't conform to anything the engine can track, so you'll have to build something yourself. In particular, it's easy to say if two databases are exactly the same database (just checksum the files) and you can distinguish backups of the same database *instance* chronologically by [LSN](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ms190729), but nothing will allow SQL Server to see what you mean by "live" and "test". The best way to prevent accidents with that, incidentally, is to firewall live and test so contamination isn't possible.

Comment: Thanks, the solution was to restore from a script which took a parameter, validated it as Live, Test or Train and then performed actions based on that. I have to rely on user action, but it was unavoidable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Database name is unique within a single instance.
It will be the only thing usable in a restore plan.

Best is to isolate production from test/dev environnements, and if you can't.
You'll have to guidelines the restore plans to reduce errors.

Comment: Also correct. Is now managed through a restore script using a user-set parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not coming back to this sooner.

Jeroen's reply was correct, i couldn't find any alternative but user-input.